# Обработка нажатия на ImageButton LibGdx

Tags: java, libgdx

`Image Button` выводится нормально, но при нажатии ничего не происходит.

```
ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle ImageButtonRight = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
ImageButtonRight.up = skin.getDrawable("button_right");
ImageButtonRight.down = skin.getDrawable("button_right");

ImageButton buttonRight = new ImageButton(ImageButtonRight);
buttonRight.setSize(200, 200);
buttonRight.setPosition(10, 10);

buttonRight.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        game.setScreen(new GameOverScreen(game));
        dispose();
    }
});

stage.addActor(buttonRight);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте эту строчку

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```